# Error: react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin react-native in android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

My app was building correctly, but two days ago, it started giving an error: "Error: react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin." I have searched extensively, but I have not been able to find a solution to fix this error.

My react native version is 0.70.10

My library is "react-native-gesture-handler"

During build it give error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI3Zu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTY5q.png)

Please help me resolve this error: "Error: react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin." I have searched extensively, but I haven't found a solution to fix this error.

want to resolve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.